# how to encrypt and decrypt data between php and android

Tags: java, php, encryption

These are my classes used in order to encrypt and decrypt data between a php based server and an android application.

Sometimes the php decrypt class does not work:

For example when I encrypt "abc" or "zdf" or "091360532561524369510" in android, the php class could not decrypt the encrypted data from the android client side.

Can you please check these classes?
**java class:**

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class ApiCrypter
{
    private String iv= "0123456789012345";
    private String secretkey= "9876543210987654";
    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public ApiCrypter()
    {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secretkey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        if(text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null) {
            return null;
        }
        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16) {
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
            else {
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP class :**

```
<?php
class ApiCrypter
{
    private $iv  = '0123456789012345';
    private $key = '9876543210987654';

    public function __construct() 
    {
    }

    public function encrypt($str)
    { 
        $str = $this->pkcs5_pad($str);   
        $iv = $this->iv; 
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv); 
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str); 
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td); 
        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    public function decrypt($code)
    { 
        $code = $this->hex2bin($code);
        $iv = $this->iv; 
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv); 
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code); 
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td); 
        $ut =  utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
        return $this->pkcs5_unpad($ut);
    }

    protected function hex2bin($hexdata)
    {
        $bindata = ''; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
            $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
        } 
        return $bindata;
    } 

    protected function pkcs5_pad ($text)
    {
        $blocksize = 16;
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }

    protected function pkcs5_unpad($text)
    {
        $pad = ord($text{strlen($text)-1});
        if ($pad > strlen($text))
        {
            return false; 
        }
        if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say 'android' you probably mean 'java'. You would need people with knowledge of java and php to look at your question. I advice you to add the 'java' tag.

Comment: Don't trim your decrypted data. Sometimes it removes the padding.

Comment: @t.m.adam wow! thats right :) very very thanks

Comment: Just so you know, your code is insecure.  It uses a fixed IV.  Under the right circumstances it would be easy to retrieve plaintext.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark thanks,I am beginner , what is your suggestion?

Comment: @XFa The IV doesn't have to be secret, just random. So use a random byte generator to create an IV and prepend it to your ciphertext. Also, consider using a KDF for your key, and replacing `mcrypt` with [`openssl`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) as `mcrypt` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Your IVs should be distinct per message and *unpredictable*; never hard-coded.
2. Don't use mcrypt in PHP.

---

This is the easiest way to solve your problem:

1. Get [libsodium in both languages](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/bindings_for_other_languages/). If you upgrade your PHP to 7.2 or newer, you should get the Sodium extension automatically (unless your OS vendor is doing something wrong).
2. Use `crypto_secretbox()` (or the equivalent API in your language) to encrypt, `crypto_secretbox_open()` to decrypt.

This is simpler than learning the proper way to fuss about with CBC mode, Initialization Vectors, padding schemes, RNGs, and ciphertext integrity.